# Copying binary file changes newline character to window's standard..? Java

Tags: java, sockets, file, newline, copying

For some reason, this code is changing any '\n' characters from the input and replacing it with '\n\r' in the new outputed file.
I reference a couple websites, and still haven't figured it out.. Anyone have an idea?
Thanks a lot!

```
Socket connectionSocket = sData.accept();
InputStream inputStream = connectionSocket.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream inputBufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/greg/1");


     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     long count = 0;
     int n = 0;
     while ((n = inputBufferedStream.read(buffer))>=0) {
         outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
         count += n;
     }
    outputStream.close();
  }
```

Comment: Can you verify that it's not the sending side that changes \n to \r\n ?

Comment: Question is based on a false premiss.

Answer (score 1):

The particular code isn't doing that. Likely those `\r\n` were simply already in the input source.

It can only happen when you're reading it using for example `BufferedReader#readLine()` which eats the newlines and writing it using `PrintWriter#println()` which appends the platform default newlines. Probably the other side is doing that? After all, a `Reader`/`Writer` shouldn't be used for binary data. It may malform it. Use `InputStream`/`OutputStream` for it.

Comment: Thank you so much! The sending data is changing the \n to \r\n

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq.